# Transaction and Rollback in Snowflake Connector for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, transactions, rollback, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using the Snowflake Connector for Python as follows:

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(user=username, password=password, account=account, warehouse=warehouse)
cs = ctx.cursor()
try:
 cs.execute(u"begin")
 cs.execute("TRUNCATE table1")
 cs.execute("TRUNCATE table2")
 cs.execute("TRUNCATE table3")
 ctx.commit()
except snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError as e:
  ctx.rollback()
  print("ERROR" + e.msg)
finally:
  cs.close()
  ctx.close()
```

Essentially I want to rollback if there are any issues with any of the SQLs (TRUNCATES). But this code doesn't seem to rollback.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: You must be interested in Transaction part of snowflake. But i think you have to use DML statement as truncate as DDL and has its own autocommit transaction, Instead you can use simple delete. [link](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/transactions.html)

Comment: @PIG, according to the Snowflake documentation, TRUNCATE is a DML command: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/truncate-table.html

Comment: Is delete not fixing the issue. ?

Comment: `TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR` have you make it as True .?

Comment: how do i set TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR using the Python Connector?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-context-manager-to-connect-and-control-transactions), you will have to set autocommit to False in order for Rollback to work, however, i am having trouble getting it to work even with it set.  Please post your findings.

```
ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(autocommit=False,user=username, password=password, account=account, warehouse=warehouse)
```